# Android studio Java - Bottom Sheet view over maps

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

new to android programming ,  java , I'm trying to create a "simple.." BottomSheet that have to appear when I click on one of my location.  Actually I've been able to create my map and load my point data. I have my map in a fragment..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"

    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I then created my BottomSheet looking at online tutorial.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinaCoordinatorLayout        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.chargesplit.android.activities.MainActivity">


 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ciao"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="ciao2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinaCoordinatorLayout>
```

Finally, inside my Main Activity, I managed to reference my bottom sheet, but probably due to inexperience I'm every time getting error on this line:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

   -> View nestedScrollView = (View) findViewById(R.id.nestedScrollView);
    mBottomSheetBehaviour = BottomSheetBehavior.from(nestedScrollView);
```

I'm always get this error and I'm probably missing a piece here...  could someone try to drive me in te right direction to understanding what's wrong?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method    'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.view.View.getLayoutParams()' on a null object   reference
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens because your activity is unable to locate your bottom sheet view, why that? because your bottom sheet view isn't included in the `activity_main.xml` layout.

In other words, Your `MainActivity.java` can only look at `activity_main.xml`, but it still has no idea about the other xml file of your bottom sheet.

To solve this: replace your code in `activity_main` layout with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinaCoordinatorLayout        
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.chargesplit.android.activities.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"/>


     <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ciao"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="ciao2"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinaCoordinatorLayout>
```

Caveat: To make your layouts look neat, you can separate your bottom sheet view into a separate layout, so you can put your `<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>` into say bottom_sheet.xml, and then reference it from the activity_main.xml with

```
<include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet" />
```

Wish that helps you out.. Should you need further help, please let me know